Handling inconsistent Power Domain States with Deferred Power-Off in GenPD Linux Device Drivers
Scenario:
The issue occurs with a UART device, where two drivers are involved:
Driver 1: AMBA bus driver (drivers/amba/bus.c) Driver 2: UART PL011 driver (drivers/tty/serial/amba-pl011.c)
Here’s the sequence of events:

Driver 1 (AMBA bus driver) attaches the UART device to read the peripheral-id. This triggers the GenPD to power on the device (genpd->status = GENPD_STATE_ON). The attach happens at line 141 in the AMBA bus driver.
Driver 1 then detaches the device, scheduling a power-off operation using genpd_queue_power_off_work(pd);. The device's power-off is deferred, and the status is not immediately set to GENPD_STATE_OFF. The detach happens at line 203.
Before the deferred power-off occurs, Driver 2 (UART PL011 driver) attaches to the UART device. GenPD finds genpd->status is set to GENPD_STATE_ON, assuming the device is powered on and therefore does not power it on again.
Eventually, the deferred power-off is executed, setting genpd->status = GENPD_STATE_OFF, and the device is powered down.

This creates an inconsistency: UART-Driver assumes the device is on, but it is actually powered off after the deferred operation, potentially leading to malfunctioning.
Question:
What is the best approach to resolve this issue, either by modifications in the genPD driver or through adjustments in the AMBA bus driver and UART PL011 driver? I'm looking for solutions that ensure the power domain status accurately reflects the current and intended state of the device, even when deferred power-off operations are in play.
Consideration I have is:

Introducing a transitional state (e.g., GENPD_STATE_POWERING_OFF) in the genPD driver and return error to UART-Driver when the UART-Driver try to attach and let the UART-Driver return -EPROBE_DEFER to the kernel, so the Kernel will have an opportunity to come back and probe again.

I would appreciate any guidance or best practices from the community on managing such scenarios, especially any existing mechanisms in the Linux kernel that can help.
Thank you!

What the exact kernel version you are talking about?

"... potentially leading to malfunctioning" - If code cannot deal with a failed read request, then that code is buggy and/or needs to be expanded to properly handle such an error condition. Examples of how to use a serial terminal device in userspace typically ignore or exit the program on read errors; such handling in a kernel driver is not appropriate.

Thanks for your response !, this is with Linux kernel version 6.1

And this is not about read request and/or user space, this is about powering sequence of the devices in the device drivers (amba/bus.c and drivers/tty/serial/amba-pl011.c) requesting thru genPD.
